# Is there a formula relating wavelength to amplitude for a sinusoidal curve of fixed line length

Tags: wave-equation

I have a piece of string of fixed length 'x'.  It is possible to lay it down in a set of sinusoidal waves of varying amplitude.  The resultant wavelength will be a function of the amplitude.  The maximum amplitude will be x/4, the minimum will be zero.  For a given amplitude, is there a formula that defines the wavelength ?

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! This is an interesting question, thank you. Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 1):

Treat the sine function as the parametric equation $x=t,y=a\sin kt$; this has amplitude *a* and wavelength $\frac{2\pi}k$. The arc length of one whole cycle is given by
$$L=\int_0^{2\pi/k}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}\ dt$$
$$=\int_0^{2\pi/k}\sqrt{1+(ka\cos kt)^2}\ dt$$
Make the substitution $u=kt$, with $\frac{du}{dt}=k$:
$$=\frac1k\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{1+(ka)^2\cos^2(u)}\ du$$
Because of the symmetries of the squared cosine function, where $\cos^2 x=\cos^2(\pi+x)=\cos^2(\pi-x)$, the integral can be divided by four:
$$=\frac4k\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+(ka)^2\cos^2u}\ du$$
$$=\frac4k\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+(ka)^2-(ka)^2\sin^2u}\ du$$
$$=\frac4k\sqrt{1+(ka)^2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-\frac{(ka)^2}{1+(ka)^2}\sin^2u}\ du$$
This last integral is in the form of the [complete elliptic integral of the second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html), and yields our final result:
$$L=\frac4k\sqrt{1+(ka)^2}E\left(\sqrt{\frac{(ka)^2}{1+(ka)^2}}\right)$$
The question now asks for $\frac{2\pi}k$ given *L* and *a*, but the relation derived above has no closed-form solution for *k*; iterative numerical methods must be used. For example, with $a=1$ and $L=8$, plonking the relation into [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=8%3D(4%2Fk)+Sqrt%5B1%2Bk%5E2%5D+EllipticE%5B(k%5E2)%2F(1%2Bk%5E2)%5D) yields $k=0.936355\dots$, whence the wavelength $\frac{2\pi}k=6.710259\dots$